# How do I create a .htaccess file so I can enter a clean URL but it processes the get requests?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a .htaccess file that changes

this url : http://www.mysite.co.uk/~username/directory1/directory2/directory3/?format=xml

to this: http://www.mysite.co.uk/~username/directory1/director2y/directory3/xml

for example you will enter the second url into the browser but the browser will process it like the first url.

I have researched .htaccess files and Rewrite rules and conditions and to be honest find it quite confusing.

The code I currently have tried using to do this is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^format=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^directory3/index.php http://www.mysite.co.uk/~username/directory1/directory2/directory3/%1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: what's the `6-2013/index.php` come from? It's not in your examples

Comment: oops forgot to edit that 6-2013 is directory3 and index.php is the file within that directory that processes the data passed by the url

Comment: I have but as it clearly states in the question I find it confusing and have therefore not been able to work it out

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+directory3/index\.php\?format=([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^ /~username/directory1/directory2/directory3/%1 [L,R=301]
```

then to rewrite it back

```
RewriteRule directory3/(.+)$ directory3/index.php?format=$1 [L]
```